# variable = a or b in erb

Tags: templates, erb, puppet

I would like to perform this simple test :

If a variable contains the string "abc" or "cba" perform task1, else perform task b Here is what I tried, which does not work :

```
<% if animal == "Meuh" || "Moooo" %>
This is a cow !
<% else %>
This is not a cow !
<% end %>
```

But This is not working.

Any hints please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERB uses the same syntax as Ruby (and most languages):

```
<% if animal == "Meuh" || animal == "Moooo" %>
```

Alternatively (especially with lots of alternatives) you can use [`Array#include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
<% if ['Meuh', 'Moooo'].include?(animal) %>
```